# the difference between the "@property" decorator in "@setter" and the usual methods

Tags: python, decorator

I am in the process of learning python. Specifically, it is about the get and set methods in the class. Question that popped up in my head is: What is the difference (apart from the call itself) between the @property and @ var.setter decorator and the regular setter.
Example:

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, mark):
        self.mark = mark
        self.__year = None

    def get_year(self):
        return self.__year

    def set_year(self, y):
        if y<2000:
            self.__year = "Old"
        else:
            self.__year = "New"

audi = Car("Audi")
audi.set_year(2005)
print(audi.get_year())
```

vs

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, mark):
        self.mark = mark
        self.__year = None

    @property
    def year(self):
        return self.__year

    @year.setter
    def year(self, y):
        if y<2000:
            self.__year = "Old"
        else:
            self.__year = "New"

audi = Car("Audi")
audi.year = 2005
print(audi.year)
```

the only difference is calling? Is there anything else in it?

Thank you for explain

Comment: Property is a little faster than explicitly calling method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the main difference is the way that the values are accessed. Having a setter with the property allows for validation like in the example you provided.

EDIT: Another benefit of properties is that it allows you to turn existing class variables into properties without having to modify code that uses these variables

See [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-property-function/) for more information about the property decorator.

Comment: Thank you for answer!As far as i know a solution using the methods alone also allows you to validate the variables

Comment: @AnnAc0nda that's true - the `@property` also allows you to turn existing normal class variables into properties with getters/setters without changing existing code that uses those variables